# Expanding a table's row when clicked on, to show another table

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a table that's rendered with a v-for. I'm trying to open a subtable/more info section for a given row, which will appear below the row which was clicked on.

I've tried adding a new tr with the existing tr, to be rendered, but it either errors, or appears to the right of the row outside, instead of underneath and inside the table

```
<tbody id="search">
                    <tr v-for="task in displayedData" v-bind:key="task.id" @click="showMoreDetail(task.id)">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" :checked="isCheckAll" /></td>
                            <td>{{task.id }}</td>                    
                            <td>{{task.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{task.hosts}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=4>
                                <div>
                                    <p>more info here</p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Above, for instance is the table body. Removing the second tr, and expanding the inner tr out of the outer tr gives the basic table, however, when I include the second tr, "task" is then undefined. I was just going to use a simple boolean to toggle display the more row, using the showMoreDetail function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using the `template` tag.

Something like this:

```html
<tbody id="search">
    <template v-for="task in displayedData">
        <tr v-bind:key="task.id" @click="showMoreDetail(task.id)">
            <td><input type="checkbox" :checked="isCheckAll" /></td>
            <td>{{task.id }}</td>                    
            <td>{{task.name }}</td>
            <td>{{task.hosts}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-bind:key="task.id + '_details'" v-if="idDetails == task.id">
            <td colspan=4>
                <div>
                    <p>more info here</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</tbody>
```

```html
<script>
    export default { 
        data() {
            return {
                idDetails: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showMoreDetail(id) {
                this.idDetails = id;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```